# Errors in saving Data, invalid data

Tags: c, database, sorting, save

Good evening, im working on a code for a project and i have encountered the following problem: the data is not saving properly after the program is shut. The data saves as multiple arrays in a txt file yet it saves strange     information, please help. Notes: the info.txt is here because the first phase ( we are at phase 2) of the project needed to, so unless it doesnt cause any problems please ignore it. same goes to the empty functions please,  in add account when we add an account we are required to move the arrays to the right

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100

void displayMainMenu();
void displayAccounts();
void addAccount(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],char    types[],int size);
void closeAccount(int ids[], double balances[],long phones[],char types[], int size);
void viewAccountDetails(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],char types[],int size);
void modifyAccountDetails();
void addAmount();
void withdrawAmount();
void uploadDataFile(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],char types[],int size);
void updateDataFile(int ids[], double balances[],long phones[], char types[],int size);

int main() {
    int choice,i=0,j=0,status;
    int id[MAXSIZE];
    char name1[MAXSIZE][30],name2[MAXSIZE][30];
    long number[MAXSIZE];
    char type[MAXSIZE];
    double balance[MAXSIZE];
    FILE*inp;
    inp=fopen("info.text","r");
    do {
        status=fscanf(inp ,"%d",&id[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%s%s" ,name1[i],name2[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%ld" ,&number[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%c" ,&type[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%lf" ,&balance[i]);
        i++;
    } while(status!=EOF);
    fclose(inp);
    uploadDataFile(id, balance,  number, type, i);
    printf("Information Loaded successfully\n");
    do {
        printf("--------main menu---------\n");
        printf("1- Add Account\n");
        printf("2- View All Accounts \n");
        printf("3- Add Amount\n");
        printf("4- Withdraw Amount\n");
        printf("5- View Account Details\n");
        printf("6- Modify Account\n");
        printf("7- Close an Account\n");
        printf("8- Exit\n");
        printf("please enter your choice:");
        scanf("%d" , &choice);

        switch(choice) {
            case 1: addAccount(id,balance,number,type,i);
                    break;
            case 2: displayAccounts(id,balance,number,type,i);
                    break;
            case 3: addAmount();
                    break;
            case 4: withdrawAmount();
                    break;
            case 5: viewAccountDetails(id,balance,number,type,i);
                    break;
            case 6: modifyAccountDetails();
                    break;
            case 7: closeAccount(id,balance,number,type,i);
                    break;
            case 8: displayMainMenu();
                    break;
            default: printf("error\n");
        }
    } while (choice!=8);
    uploadDataFile( id, balance, number, type, i);
    printf("Thank you,the information has been updated successfully!\n");

    return 0;
}

void displayMainMenu() {
    printf("displays the main menu\n");
}

void displayAccounts(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],
                     char types[],int size) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("The id is:%d\t\t The balance is:%f\nThe phone number is:%d\t The   type is:%s\n",ids[i],balances[i],phones[i],types[i]);
}

void addAccount(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],char types[],int size) {
    int i=0,temp,id,flag,j;
    double temp2,balance;
    long temp3,phone;
    char temp4,type;
    printf("Please enter the account's new id\n");
    scanf("%d",&id);
    if(size<MAXSIZE) {
        while(i<size) {
            if(id==ids[i]) {
                flag=1;
                break;
            } else {
                flag=0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==0) {
        for(i=size;i>0;i--) {
            ids[i]=ids[i-1];
            balances[i]=balances[i-1];
            phones[i]=phones[i-1];
            types[i]=types[i-1];
        }
        ids[0]=id;
        for(j=0;j<size-1;j++) {
            for(i=1;i<size;i++) {
                temp=ids[i-1];
                temp2=balances[i-1];
                temp3=phones[i-1];
                temp4=types[i-1];
                ids[i-1]=ids[i];
                balances[i-1]=balances[i];
                phones[i-1]=phones[i];
                types[i-1]=types[i];
                ids[i]=temp;
                balances[i]=temp2;
                phones[i]=temp3;
                types[i]=temp4;
            }
        }
        printf("Please enter the account's  balance\n");
        scanf("%lf",&balance);
        printf("Please enter the account's  phone number\n");
        scanf("%ld",&phone);
        printf("Please enter the account's  type \n");
        scanf(" %c",&type);
        balances[0]=balance;
        phones[0]=phone;
        types[0]=type;
        printf("Account added!\n");
    } else
        ("the Id is already in use\n");
}

void closeAccount(int ids[], double balances[],long phones[],
                  char types[], int size) {
    int i,j;
    int id;
    printf("please enter the id u want to close\n");
    scanf("%d",&id);
    if(size>0) {
        for(i=0;j<size;j++) {
            for(i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
                if(id==ids[i]) {
                    ids[i]=ids[i+1];
                    balances[i]=balances[i+1];
                    phones[i]=phones[i];
                    types[i]=types[i+1];
                } else
                    printf("error\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void viewAccountDetails(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],char types[],int size) {
    int id,i=0,flag;
    printf("Please input the id for the desired account\n");
    scanf("%d",&id); 
    if(size>0) {
        while(i<size) {
            if(id==ids[i]) {
                flag=1;
                break;
            } else {
                flag=0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
        printf("The account information are:\n id: %d/t balance: %f\t phone number:%ld\t Type: %c",ids[i],balances[i],phones[i],types[i]);
    else
        printf("Error: The account was not found\n");
}

void modifyAccountDetails() {
    printf("modifies a certain account details ");
}

void addAmount() {
    printf("increases the balance variable");
}

void withdrawAmount() {
    printf("decreases the balance variable");
}

void uploadDataFile(int ids[],double balances[],long phones[],char types[],int size) {
    FILE*inp;
    inp=fopen("Accounts.txt","r");
    int i=1;
    while(i<size) {
        fscanf(inp ,"%d",&ids[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%ld" ,&phones[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%c" ,&types[i]);
        fscanf(inp ,"%lf" ,&balances[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void updateDataFile(int ids[], double balances[], long phones[], char types[], int size) {
    FILE*out;
    out=fopen("Accounts.txt","w");
    fprintf(out,"%d\n",ids);
    fprintf(out,"%f\n",balances); 
    fprintf(out,"%ld\n",phones);
    fprintf(out,"%c\n",types);
}
```

Comment: You should close some files, somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Getting compiler warnings. If we fix warnings first then we know better.

```
$ gcc database.c 
database.c: In function ‘displayAccounts’:
database.c:86:11: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("The id is:%d\t\t The balance is:%f\nThe phone number is:%d\t The   t
           ^
database.c:86:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
database.c: In function ‘updateDataFile’:
database.c:243:16: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    fprintf(out,"%d\n",ids);
                ^
database.c:244:16: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
    fprintf(out,"%f\n",balances); 
                ^
database.c:245:16: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat=]
    fprintf(out,"%ld\n",phones);
                ^
database.c:246:16: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
    fprintf(out,"%c\n",types);
```

You can make a minimal example in http://ideone.com/ and exclude the file i/o and use printf only and see where the problem is, if not in the warnings above.

The warnings mean that your types are wrong but the code is still runnable and you will get undefined behavior from the program or similar if you mix different types. Be careful what's a pointer and what's data.